# Python main process getting stuck

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

My main process couldn't continue after calling `join` for the child processes, these are the long run child processes, and I can confirm that they finished running, because I check the `queue` result before doing the `join`. So the main process didn't run anything for almost 10 minutes, until I decide to close the terminal window, at this moment it run a little more commands, I know this because I logged the command into a debug file. I'd like to know what kind of behavior is this, why it continues at the moment I close the terminal.

P.S. Sometimes this bug happened, sometimes the code works fine until the end. I added the code related to the parallel part below. If the bug happened, normally it's right after I call `join` on a child process, but I knew that child process is supposed to be finished already thanks to `status_dict`

```
with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        semaphore = manager.Semaphore(value=param_config.max_process) 
        status_dict = manager.dict()
        l_id = -1
        list_process = []
        while l_id <= max_link_id:
            
            proc_amount = 0
            
            if l_id >= max_link_id:
                l_id += 1
            
            while proc_amount < param_config.batch_size and l_id < max_link_id:
                l_id += 1
                
                
                proc_amount += 1
                semaphore.acquire()
                process = TabuProcess(result_queue, l_id, map_slot, map_dual_values, map_C_pi, map_lightpath_id.values(), \
                                      graph, map_config_generator[l_id].map_route_link, map_config_generator[l_id].map_request_route, \
                                      semaphore, status_dict)
                            
                list_process.append(process)
                process.start()
                  
            while not result_queue.empty():
                lid, map_slot, _reduce_cost = result_queue.get()
                
            
            if l_id < max_link_id:
                t_list = list(list_process)
                for proc in t_list:
                    if status_dict[proc.link_id]:
                        
                        proc.join()
                        list_process.remove(proc)
                    
            elif l_id == max_link_id:
                
                while len(list_process) > 0:
                    t_list = list(list_process)
                    for proc in t_list:
                        
                        if status_dict[proc.link_id]:
                            
                            list_process.remove(proc)
                            
                            proc.join()
                            
                        else:
                            
                    if len(list_process) > 0:
                        
                        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: some terminals will get stuck when you switch focus to them, usually pressing any button or return gets it to work again ... this has bugged me ever since i started coding, and i have seen this behavior on many terminals.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I tried what you suggested, it didn't work. I'm currently using Anaconda prompt to run my program.

Comment: please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not much here for us to go on.

Comment: @Aaron I tried that with a simpler code, with a main process spawn like 8 child processes, which would run for sometimes, but the main process never getting stuck.